# Making a CORS request to Google Static Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to make a CORS request to Google's static maps api and return an image to be mounted on canvas (to avoid canvas's Cross Origin protection). I'm not sure if I'm following the instructions correctly (https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/cors) but the xhr request never returns anything.

```
const position = latLngArg;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 
`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=${position.lat()},${position.lng()}&zoom=20&size=20x20&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyBiE2efHKeAptVfVRtj9-ZDeHWPKgNjdNk`)
 .then(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `XMLHttlRequest` `open` method does not return a promise.

It also does not send the request it only initialize it. In order to set the request you need to call the `send` method afterwards.

You should register a callback to be triggered upon success by setting the `onreadystatechange` property.

See an example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Native XHR do not work with promises.

You can try the following:

```
const position = latLngArg;
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
const address = `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=${position.lat()},${position.lng()}&zoom=20&size=20x20&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyBiE2efHKeAptVfVRtj9-ZDeHWPKgNjdNk`;

xhr.open('GET', address);
xhr.onload = () => onImageReceived(xhr.response);
xhr.send();

function onImageReceived(image) {
    console.log(image);
}
```

You can verify that the `xhr.response` will be your image, after the request was completed (`onload` event).

Read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp).